# Unable to install spatie laravel-backup package on my windows 10 PC PHP Version 8.0.3, Laravel Version 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hi I am unable to install Laravel backup package spatie laravel backup

Showing below error massages

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-backup ^7.6 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-backup[7.6.0].
- spatie/laravel-backup 7.6.0 requires ext-pcntl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pcntl extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- F:\server8030\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Any one can help me to success

Comment: Enable ext-pcntl in the php.ini file. That the error, that extension is needed for installation

Comment: There is not found "ext-pcntl" in my php.ini file
Can you please let me know another way or how solve the problem.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/requirements), that library is "not compatible with Windows servers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a workaround using spatie/laravel-backup 7.3.3.
I needed to start using test --parallel, and for that install brianium/paratest and with spatie/laravel-backup  ^7.6 it was not possible for the error you informed.
So if spatie/laravel-backup in version 7.3.3 is enough for what you need try:

> composer require spatie/laravel-backup ^7.3.3

Or use a unix machine

As informed by @Chris Haas
According to the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/requirements), ext-pcntl * library is "not compatible with Windows servers"

Comment: Thank you so much. It's installed by composer require spatie/laravel-backup ^7.3.3